# Updating react state with a similar object

Tags: reactjs, state

Please note, this is a very oversimplified example of my code. I have a state:

```
this.state = {
  first: "",
  second: "",
  third: ""
}
```

I want to change my state like so:

```
this.getAppData(localStorage.getItem("application_id")).then(res => this.setState( prevState => {
        ...prevState.state,
        res.data
}))
```

While res.data is :

```
{
first: "updatedValue1",
third: "updatedValue2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer, all res.data key values now overwrite matching state values:

```
        this.getAppData(localStorage.getItem("application_id")).then(res =>
            this.setState({ ...this.state, ...res.data })
        );
```

Comment: The `...this.state` is unnecessary as `setState` does a merge and not replace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    this.getAppData(localStorage.getItem("application_id")).then(res =>
        this.setState((state) => ({ ...state, ...res.data }))
    );
```